# Order of execution for prepared statement in php

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I've read everything there is to read about prepared statements and im still not sure about the order of execution... (many use different order).

Is this a good order ?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... = ?';

$conn = ...connection to database...
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); // results are cached and accessed from memeory, therefore faster but use more memory
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows; // how many? (can only be use with store_result() )
$stmt->bind_result($column, ...);
$stmt->fetch(); // use in loop if necessary
$stmt->free_result(); // use only with store_result()
$stmt->close(); // close prepared statement
$conn->close(); // close database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not.

Although order is quite all right, many operators you have used are superfluous and useless. Also, there should be no connection related code in the context of execution single query.

```
include 'db.php'; // here goes connect
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... = ?';
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($column, ...);
$stmt->fetch();
```

is enough. Note that you never need row_count if you have data.